# Python: replace some tags to html tags in string

Tags: python, html, regex

I have some text, example:

> My text \b the best \b
>
> but i cant do this \a task because
>
> this is fu** regex? And other text

How can I replace these tags with HTML tags like the following:

> My text  the best
>
> but i cant do this  task  because
>
> this is fu** regex? And other text

Tag \b in pair, but \a not in pair and must include only next word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two separate replacements:

```
sample = re.sub(r'\\b(.*?)\\b', r'<h5>\1</h5>', sample)
sample = re.sub(r'\\a(\s*\w+)', r'<a href="#task">\1</a>', sample)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> sample = '''\
... My text \\b the best \\b
... but i cant do this \\a task because
... this is fu** regex? And other text
... '''
>>> sample = re.sub(r'\\b(.*?)\\b', r'<h5>\1</h5>', sample)
>>> sample = re.sub(r'\\a(\s*\w+)', r'<a href="#task">\1</a>', sample)
>>> sample
'My text <h5> the best </h5>\nbut i cant do this <a href="#task"> task</a> because\nthis is fu** regex? And other text\n'
>>> print sample
My text <h5> the best </h5>
but i cant do this <a href="#task"> task</a> because
this is fu** regex? And other text
```